# Flutter: I want to open another app from a flutter app, passing some arguments. Is that possible?

Tags: flutter, android-intent, launch

I have tried using the flutter package : appavailability, but cannot pass arguments with it.
I have tried url_launcher, but it is helpful to launch only the web urls.
I have tried DeviceApps and android_intent something like this:

````
```static openApp(String url) async {
    bool isInstalled = await DeviceApps.isAppInstalled(url);
    if (isInstalled != false) {
      String dt = 'userId';
      AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(action: 'action_send', data: dt, package: url);
      await intent.launch();
    } else {
      throw "Could not open app $url";
    }
  }
````

```
Even this doesn't work. 
Gives error : E/flutter (16289): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method isAppInstalled on channel g123k/device_apps).

Does any one know the correct working code to do this?
```

Comment: If you just added the plugin and perform a hot restart, it wont work. Re-run the app for plugins to work.